# change grid mode to list mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to know how I can change a view from grid to list and that the When changing pages stay with the selected view.

Adjunte a example in  pictures.

thanks for help me.

my script:

```js
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
  $('#list').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#container div').addClass('list');
  });
  $('#grid').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#container div').removeClass('list');
    $('#container div').addClass('grid');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons" style=" padding: 10px;">
  <button id="grid" class="grid">Grid View</button>
  <button id="list" class="list">List View</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't bind event-handler inside other event-handlers

Comment: Hi, how are you, thanks for helping me? I'm new to this, Can you guide me? as would be?

Comment: What does your html for the buttons look like? You probably just can omit the first event-handler for `button`. To save the state of whether it is list or grid mode have a look at [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: <div class="buttons" style=" padding: 10px;">
  <button id="grid" class="grid">Grid View</button>
  <button id="list" class="list">List View</button>
</div> thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can omit the first event-handler in your case. I would recommend wrapping everything in a `ready`-handler. You can use localStorage/sessionStorage to save the state of your layout and check it on page-load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var mode = localStorage.getItem('mode');

 if(mode){
    $('#container div').addClass(mode === 'grid' ? 'grid' : 'list');
 }

 $('#list').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#container div').removeClass('grid');
   $('#container div').addClass('list');
   localStorage.setItem('mode', 'list');
 });
 $('#grid').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#container div').removeClass('list');
   $('#container div').addClass('grid');
   localStorage.setItem('mode', 'grid');
 });
});
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/x9f3qr7k/)

---

References:

[document-ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

[ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: Thanks to my friend it is difficult to understand, but hey, I'll work with this, it's very helpful, your answer

Comment: @AlvaroMejia glad to help, if an answer works for you make sure to accept it if it answers your question.